# Two navbars with sticky

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create two navbars that are below each other. The idea is that for navbar-1 sticky is not added until I scroll up in between the webpage or when I reach the end of the page. So until I do either of the two, navbar-1 will be invisible. Navbar-2 which is below navbar-1 will have normal sticky i.e., as I scroll past the div, the navbar-2 will be fixed at the top of the page. What I am trying to do this to have both of them work simultaneously. ie, when I scroll down, navbar-1 will go invisible and navbar two will be fixed at the top until I scroll up then navbar-2 will move down to accommodate navbar-1. I wrote javascript to try and achieve this but only one of the functions is working. Can anyone tell me how I can achieve this? I am attaching part of my code below

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction();
  scrollDetect();
};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var navbar2 = document.getElementById("navbar2");
var divAboveHeading = document.getElementById("navbar"); 
var gapBetweenElements = 50; 
var stickyOffset = divAboveHeading.offsetTop + divAboveHeading.offsetHeight + gapBetweenElements; // Calculate the offset

function scrollDetect() {
  var lastScroll = 0;
  let currentScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop; // Get Current Scroll Value

  if (currentScroll > 0 && lastScroll <= currentScroll) {
    lastScroll = currentScroll;
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  } else {
    lastScroll = currentScroll;
    navbar.classList.add("sticky");
  }

  if (currentScroll < 100) {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}


function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= stickyOffset) {
    navbar2.classList.add("sticky2");
  } else {
    navbar2.classList.remove("sticky2");
  }
}
```

```css
.main-navbar{
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-flex;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  top: 2.4rem;
  height: 4.5rem;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 101;
}

.heading {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 10rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 100;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  animation: faceInEffect 0.3s;
  -webkit-animation: faceInEffect 0.3s;
}

@keyframes faceInEffect {
  from {
    top: -5rem;
  }
  to {
    top: 0rem;
  }
}

.sticky2 {
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
}

.content{
position: absolute;
top:100rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="main-navbar" id="navbar">
    <div>
      <a>Test</a>
      <a>Test2</a>
      <a>Test3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>


<div class="heading" id="navbar2">
  <div>
    <h2>Content</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="">Test2</a>
    <a href="">Test3</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <p> contetn to scroll</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working sample of the implementation for your reference: https://codepen.io/bikramjethi/pen/VwqdWdz

Explanation: So, I'm assuming a simple markup for your use case, where we have 2 navbars, stacked together and then the page content follows. For my example, the navbars have an ID of `navbar1` and `navbar2`. The idea is to always have `position: sticky;` attached to both the navbars, upon show/hide of `nav1` we just toggle the top values for both the navbars. This toggle logic will be based on the `height` of the first nav;

I suggest adding an event listener to your window object for the scroll event. Let's call this method `handleScroll` and a variable that tracks the last scroll value for the window instance called `lastScrollY`.

```
let nav1 = document.getElementById("navbar1");
let nav2 = document.getElementById("navbar2");
let lastScrollY = window.pageYOffset;
window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
```

This `handleScroll` method internally tracks the scroll direction of the user. When the user scrolls up, it invokes a `setNav1Sticky` when the user scrolls down it invokes a `setNav1NonSticky` method.

```
function handleScroll() {
  console.log("scroll triggered");
  const scrollY = window.pageYOffset;
  const isScrollUp = scrollY < lastScrollY;
  if(isScrollUp) {
    setNav1Sticky();
  } else {
    setNav1NonSticky();
  }
  lastScrollY = scrollY;
}
```

Here is how the contents of `setNav1Sticky` and `setNav1NonSticky` would look like. Assuming a fixed nav height of `26.5px`(will vary for your case so update logic accordingly).

```
function setNav1Sticky() {
  nav1.style.top = 0;
  nav2.style.top = "26.5px";
}

function setNav1NonSticky() {
  nav1.style.top = "-26.5px";
  nav2.style.top = 0;
}
```

Also, note that both navbars have a `transition: top 0.5s;` CSS property attached to them for a smoother show/hide effect.

Hope this helps, please accept the answer if this unblocked you.

Comment: hey, i cannot use postion as sticky becuase there are more divs above my navbar-1. Further, I want gap between navbar-1 and navbar-2, which is not working with sticky

Comment: @kangkong Can you share a codepen implementation url for your example ?